# Nodemailer: How to send Email with icalEvent and attachments both

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send Email using Nodemailer. I need to send an email with attachments and calendar-invitation. but in Email, I am only receiving calendar invitation, not attachments. how can I achieve it?

although Nodemailer itself suggest not to send attachments and calender-invitation together. but I need to develop this functionality at any cost.

[image]

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
castCalender = require('../helpers/cast-calendar-to-email'),
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
    secureConnection: false,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER, // generated ethereal user
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD, // generated ethereal password
    },
})

module.exports = (to, subject, html, attachments = null, calendar = null) => {
return transporter.sendMail({
    from: process.env.SMTP_USER, // sender address
    to: to, // list of receivers
    subject: subject, // Subject line
    html: html, // html body
    // alternatives: castCalender(calendar),
    attachments: attachments,
    icalEvent: {
        method: 'request',
        content: castCalender(calendar)
    }
})
```

}

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/message/calendar-events/

Comment: What exactly is not working? I don't see where the question is? What is the error?

Comment: when I tried to send an email with both attachments and calendar, then the calendar removes/override all attachments other than the calendar icon.